# What relational database management system RDBMS for small read-only DB on a linux web server with unixODBC?

Tags: mysql, sqlite, webserver, rdbms, unixodbc

What can be considered the best RDBMS for a web application to query database tables located on the web server host machine, which has linux OS with unixODBC installed? The database tables are small and need just read-only access.

SQLite3 or mySQL or something else?

I'm leaning towards SQLite3, but is it mature?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLite is very mature.  It is included in major applications, including Firefox, Android, Adobe Integrated Mountie, Python, Mac OS and Skype.

I think it's very appropriate for a small read-only database.